# Parameter type may not live long enough (with threads)

Tags: rust

This is similar to [Parameter type may not live long enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740488/parameter-type-may-not-live-long-enough), but my interpretation of the solution doesn't seem to be working. My original boiled-down test case is:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::thread;

trait HasFeet: Debug + Send + Sync + Clone {}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Person;

impl HasFeet for Person {}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Cordwainer<A: HasFeet> {
    shoes_for: A,
}

impl<A: HasFeet> Cordwainer<A> {
    fn make_shoes(&self) {
        let cloned = self.shoes_for.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("making shoes for = {:?}", cloned);
        });
    }
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `A` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:19:9
   |
16 | impl<A: HasFeet> Cordwainer<A> {
   |      -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `A: 'static`...
...
19 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src/main.rs:19:23: 21:10 cloned:A]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:19:9
   |
19 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Instead of making `A` `'static`, I go through and add an explicit lifetime to the `HasFeet` trait:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::thread;

trait HasFeet<'a>: 'a + Send + Sync + Debug {}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Person;

impl<'a> HasFeet<'a> for Person {}

struct Cordwainer<'a, A: HasFeet<'a>> {
    shoes_for: A,
}

impl<'a, A: HasFeet<'a>> Cordwainer<'a, A> {
    fn make_shoes(&self) {
        let cloned = self.shoes_for.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("making shoes for = {:?}", cloned);
        })
    }
}
```

This now gives me the error:

```
error[E0392]: parameter `'a` is never used
  --> src/main.rs:11:19
   |
11 | struct Cordwainer<'a, A: HasFeet<'a>> {
   |                   ^^ unused type parameter
   |
   = help: consider removing `'a` or using a marker such as `std::marker::PhantomData`
```

I think that `'a` is used as the lifetime parameter to the `HasFeet` trait. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you not want to bound `A` by the `'static` lifetime when you spawn it? I'm pretty sure that you will **have to**, based on the fact that the spawned thread may outlive the parent thread. The [restriction is pretty non-invasive as well](http://is.gd/EjUX6Y).

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what the meaning of `'static` is in this context. I don't want to make the `A` that gets used in `make_shoes` to be leaked by forcing it to live for the duration of the program.

Comment: It certainly won't be leaked. Basically, you will be transferring ownership of the variable to the thread, and the variable is not allowed to have any *references* to items that cannot be guaranteed to live for the life of the program.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`std::thread::spawn()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) function is declared with a `Send + 'static` bound on its closure. Anything which this closure captures must satisfy the `Send + 'static` bound. There is *no* way around this in safe Rust. If you want to pass data to other threads using this function, it must be `'static`, period.

It is possible to lift the `'static` restriction with the proper API, see [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423) for an example.

However, a `'static` bound is not as scary as it may seem. First of all, you cannot *force* anything to do anything with lifetime bounds (you can't *force* anything to do anything with any kind of bounds). Bounds just limit the set of types which can be used for the bounded type parameter and that is all; if you tried to pass a value whose type does not satisfy these bounds, the compiler will fail to compile your program, it won't magically make the values "live longer".

Moreover, a `'static` bound does not mean that the value must live for the duration of the program; it means that the value must not contain borrowed references with lifetimes other than `'static`. In other words, it is a lower bound for possible references inside the value; if there are no references, then the bound does not matter. For example, `String` or `Vec<u64>` or `i32` satisfy the `'static` bound.

`'static` is a very natural restriction to put on `spawn()`. If it weren't present, the values transferred to another thread could contain references to the stack frame of the parent thread. If the parent thread finishes before the spawned thread, these references would become dangling.