# Is there a more idiomatic way to use traits like `io::Read` with lifetimes?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a public trait, `Parser`, that defines an external interface.  I then have a private `ParserImpl` struct that implements the methods (actually, I have several implementations, which is the idea behind using the trait to abstract away).

```
use std::io;

pub trait Parser {
    // ...omitted
}

struct ParserImpl<R: io::Read> {
    // ...omitted
    stream: R,
}

impl<R: io::Read> ParserImpl<R> {
    // ...methods
    fn new(stream: R) -> ParserImpl<R> {
        ParserImpl {
            // ...omitted
            stream: stream,
        }
    }
}

impl<R: io::Read> Parser for ParserImpl<R> {
    // ...methods
}
```

To create a parser instance, I use a function to hide `ParserImpl`.

```
pub fn make_parser<'a, R>(stream: R) -> Box<Parser + 'a>
where
    R: io::Read + 'a,
{
    Box::new(ParserImpl::new(stream))
}
```

This is all well and good... and it works... but the `make_parser` function troubles me. I feel that there must be a simpler way to approach this and like I'm missing something important, as this seems like a potential pitfall whenever using a trait like `io::Read` to abstract away the source of data.

I understand the need to specify lifetimes ([Parameter type may not live long enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740488/parameter-type-may-not-live-long-enough)) but I am a bit stumped on whether I can have both a clean and simple interface, and also use a trait like `io::Read`.

Is there a "cleaner," or perhaps more idiomatic way, to use traits like `io::Read` that I am missing?  If not, that's okay, but I'm pretty new to Rust and when I wrote the above function I kept thinking "this can't be right..."

To make this sample runnable, here's a `main`:

```
fn main() {
    use std::fs;
    let file: fs::File = fs::File::open("blabby.txt").unwrap();
    let parser = make_parser(file);
}
```

Comment: *I use a function to hide `ParserImpl`* — Why do you think that is a valuable thing to do in this case? *this seems like a potential pitfall* — What kind of pitfall do you imagine could happen?

Comment: This is the simplified version.  There are multiple parser implementations, all of which present the same `Parser` interface.  The rest of the code needs to be agnostic to the specific parser being used.

Comment: Were you aware that you can [implement a trait for a box of that trait](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33041736/155423)? Then this function doesn't have to be the one that performs the boxing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *is* the idiomatic way of writing the code that has that meaning, but you may not want that meaning.

For example, if you don't *need* to create a boxed trait object, you can just return the parameterized value directly, or in this case just use the result of `ParserImpl::new`. This is my default form until I know I need dynamic dispatch provided by some trait object.

You could also require the `'static` lifetime instead of introducing a new lifetime `'a`, but this reduces the range of allowed types that you can pass into `make_parser`:

```
pub fn make_parser<R>(stream: R) -> Box<Parser>
where
    R: io::Read + 'static,
{
    Box::new(ParserImpl::new(stream))
}
```

Comment: @StacyProwell perhaps this question is really a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423 then?

Comment: Not sure how I could return the value directly; wouldn't I still need to specify the lifetime?

Comment: Ah!  Yes, "let the compiler guide you."  Please keep in mind I'm coming from C++, where the compiler was designed to actively hate you.

Comment: @StacyProwell If you think that's a more comprehensive answer, you are encouraged to un-accept this and then you can mark your question as a duplicate of that.