# the parameter type may not live long enough (again?) (in closure)

Tags: rust, static, traits, lifetime

In trying to compile the code

```
fn make<DomainType>(foo: fn(DomainType) -> ()) -> Box<dyn Fn(DomainType) -> ()> {                                                                                                                                                 
    let foo_clone = foo.clone();                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    let bar = move |input: DomainType| {foo_clone(input)};                                                                                                                                                                        
    Box::new(bar)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
fn main() {}
```

The compiler gives

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `DomainType` may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     Box::new(bar)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `[closure@src/main.rs:3:15: 3:58]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
  |
1 | fn make<DomainType: 'static>(foo: fn(DomainType) -> ()) -> Box<dyn Fn(DomainType) -> ()> {
  |                   +++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0310`.
```

I have been reading through similar questions
[Parameter type may not live long enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740488/parameter-type-may-not-live-long-enough)
and
[The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053550/the-compiler-suggests-i-add-a-static-lifetime-because-the-parameter-type-may-no)

But in both of those examples, the boxed trait is what needs the added lifetime.  In this case it's apparently just the DomainType of the closure trait.  I'm quite baffled what to make of this.

My understanding of lifetime variables in function definitions is that they connect the lifetime of the returned type (which I can understand is implicitly static here, or at least the thing inside the box is) to those (perhaps elided) lifetimes of the function parameters.  But no function parameter here is a `DomainType`.

Comment: What's wrong with doing exactly what it says? Adding `'static` to the generic? Most people have an incorrect understanding of what 'static means .. It does **not** mean "lives for the entire program", in this case it primarily means "does not depend on other variables". Only if you are dealing with references then it normally means "lives for the entire program", because you can't have a reference that depends on no variable without being static.

Comment: @Finomnis Well that is what I'm trying to figure out.  How am I supposed to know what use of static is being used?  E.g. in this example https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41966 adding static is the Wrong thing to do (and note that references are not explicitly mentioned in the client code).

Comment: Minor nit: `-> ()` is redundant and can simply be omitted.

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER**: This question goes very deep into Rust compiler specifics, and I'm not 100% sure about everything I say here. Take everything with a grain of salt.

---

The problem here is that `Box<T>` means that `T` is `'static` if no lifetime is annotated.

A generic, however, does not mean that. A generic could contain any kind of lifetime. To match the two, you need an explicit lifetime annotation.

### Solution 1

You **could** annotate `'static` to the generic, like this:

```rust
fn make<DomainType: 'static>(foo: fn(DomainType)) -> Box<dyn Fn(DomainType)> {
    Box::new(foo)
}
```

That, however, would create problems if you do actually encounter the case where the generic carries a lifetime:

```rust
fn my_func(x: &str) {
    println!("my_func: {}", x);
}

fn main() {
    let x = "abc".to_string();

    let f = make(my_func);
    f(&x);
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:7
   |
13 |     f(&x);
   |     --^^-
   |     | |
   |     | borrowed value does not live long enough
   |     argument requires that `x` is borrowed for `'static`
14 | }
   | - `x` dropped here while still borrowed
```

### Solution 2

The proper way here is to solve the initial mismatch by telling the compiler that the lifetimes attached to the generic match the lifetimes contained in the Box.

Like this:

```rust
fn make<'a, DomainType: 'a>(foo: fn(DomainType)) -> Box<dyn Fn(DomainType) + 'a> {
    Box::new(foo)
}
```

And it now works:

```rust
fn my_func(x: &str) {
    println!("my_func: {}", x);
}

fn main() {
    let x = "abc".to_string();

    let f = make(my_func);
    f(&x);
}
```

```
my_func: abc
```

### Problems

There are still problems with this. I'm unsure how/if they are solvable, though.

The problem is that the resulting `Box` object will always be bound to a **specific** lifetime. Look for example at this:

```rust
fn make<'a, DomainType: 'a>(foo: fn(DomainType)) -> Box<dyn Fn(DomainType) + 'a> {
    Box::new(foo)
}

fn my_func(x: &str) {
    println!("my_func: {}", x);
}

fn make2() -> Box<dyn Fn(&str)> {
    Box::new(|x| println!("closure: {}", x))
}

fn main() {
    let x = "abc".to_string();

    let f = make(my_func);
    let f2 = make2();

    let fs = [f2, f];
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:19:19
   |
19 |     let fs = [f2, f];
   |                   ^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected trait object `dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str)`
              found trait object `dyn Fn(&str)`
```

`f2` here takes all objects that can be borrowed. `f` only takes objects that all can be borrowed with the **same** lifetime, as `'a` resolves when `make` is called, not when `f` is executed.

Another example is this:

```rust
fn make<'a, DomainType: 'a>(foo: fn(DomainType)) -> Box<dyn Fn(DomainType) + 'a> {
    Box::new(foo)
}

fn my_func(x: &str) {
    println!("my_func: {}", x);
}

fn make2() -> Box<dyn Fn(&str)> {
    Box::new(|x| println!("closure: {}", x))
}

fn main() {
    let f = make(my_func);
    let f2 = make2();

    {
        let x = "abc".to_string();
        f2(&x); // Works
        f(&x); // Fails to compile
    }
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:20:11
   |
20 |         f(&x); // Fails to compile
   |           ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
21 |     }
   |     - `x` dropped here while still borrowed
22 | }
   | - borrow might be used here, when `f` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Box<dyn Fn(&str)>`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined
```

I don't think this is solvable, though. I think generics can't carry generic lifetimes, they can only carry specific lifetimes. And said specific lifetime gets resolved at the point where `make()` is called.

Although a proper explanation would require someone with a deeper Rust compiler understanding than me. If something like this exists, I'd be interested in it as well. (something like `DomainType: for<'a>` or similar)

I can see that one of the example's output says it would require a `dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str)`. I don't know, however, if something like this is annotatable by hand or if it's something internal to the compiler. But that would be what is required - instead of `Box<dyn Fn(DomainType) + 'a>`, we would need something like `Box<dyn for <'r> Fn(DomainType + 'r)>`. Again, I don't know if/how this is annotatable, and if it is, I'd also be interested in it.

Comment: I don't think you can annotate the lifetime so it will be general (late bound).

Comment: Still struggling with the concept of early and late bound :) I guess that's kind what I was trying to talk about, I'm just missing the proper vocabulary ... might have to read up on it again. Thanks for confirming my gut feeling :)

Answer (score 0):

Could [Higher Rank Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) be what you're looking for?

```rust
fn make<F, DomainType>(foo: F) -> Box<dyn Fn(DomainType)>
where
    for<'r> F: Fn(DomainType) + Clone + 'r
{
    let foo_clone = foo.clone();
    let bar = move |input: DomainType| {foo_clone(input)};
    Box::new(bar)
}
```

If the purpose of the function is to consume a closure and return it in a Box, I don't think you need the Clone trait. In fact, it doesn't even need to be nested in a new closure. Just directly box it.

```rust
fn make<F, DomainType>(foo: F) -> Box<dyn Fn(DomainType)> 
where 
    for<'r> F: Fn(DomainType) + 'r 
{
    Box::new(foo)
}
```

Unless you want to pass in a reference to a closure that doesn't get consumed:

```rust
fn make<F, DomainType>(foo: &F) -> Box<dyn Fn(DomainType)> 
where 
    for<'r> F: Fn(DomainType) + Clone + 'r 
{
    Box::new(foo.clone())
}
```